# In asp.net Grid view control whether it is possible to bind the data to the cell of gridview without using SQL or sql connection

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net Grid view control whether it is possible to bind the data to the cell of gridview without using SQL or SQL connection

Comment: do you meant to manually add data to cells... like grideview1.Rows[1].cells[2]="data1";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is so many ways to bind data with datagridview like arrays, generics and more

check the below links

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33748

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/DataSourcewithGenericCollection.htm